# Money stoped by UK fraud dept

Tags: united-kingdom, inheritance

My fiancee got her inheritance from her father's account  he put in the bank before he died. Now it had the stamps to leave UK but was stopped by UK in Canada, because it could be money laundering or drug money. Now to get it out of UK's hold she has to hire a lawyer and pay up front for the lawyer. Does this sound right because we have never dealt with anything like this and don't know what to do.

Comment: Are you sure this is not some kind of scam? Who has recommended the lawyer and who contacted you about the transfer stuck in UK fraud

Comment: the bank of uk contacted her and sent a tkt to the UK n now she's over there and the bank also notified us bout the stop on the money and the bank is there lawyer that they recommended

Comment: and checking out the bank and the person i'm dealing with has had scam reports on him

Comment: also she is over there on a flight bought by the bank , how do i get her back here in the USA ; because we don't have the money to get her back here if she loses the money

Comment: You need to be much more precise with your wording to get a useful answer. There’s no “UK fraud dept”; what is the actual exact name of the organisation you’re referring to? What exactly do you mean by “stamps to leave the UK”? You can’t “hire a lawyer” in the UK, because they’re called solicitors (or barristers, but you won’t be hiring a barrister). And so on and so forth.

Comment: One question - Do you know this person in real life, or just on line?

Comment: @wildman28602 "_also she is over there on a flight bought by the bank_" while I can't prove a bank would _never_ do this, I cannot imagine for a minute that a bank that has frozen money due to suspected laundering would _ever_ pay for the intended recipient to fly to another country. Sorry to be blunt, but do you _**actually know**_ (in any kind of real-life sense) the fiancee (and/or the father), or is she "just" someone you've been meeting online, and all the details about the inheritance have come from her? If the latter, it's almost certainly a scam.

Answer (score 8):

You can usually tell when banks suspect money laundering, because they go very quiet, and refuse to discuss things. Banks will no more contact you to say they suspect money laundering, than the phone company will to say your phone is being tapped. It would be illegal for them to do so.

The first thing is: who is the executor for your fiancee's father's estate? Someone needs to have registered the death, and got a grant of probate (a legal document saying that they have the authority to access the money, and settle her late father's affairs - like selling his house). Usually this would be a relative or lawyer rather than a bank. So, who cleared his house, paid his bills... why are you not talking to them rather than some 'bank'?

Sorry, but this stinks. Advice for your fiancee: assume there is no money: the money is the bait, unless you can let go of it, you'll be on the hook. Don't trust anything they say, or the lawyer they recommend. Go to  [Citizen's Advice](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/) and say that you think you are being scammed, or even the police.

As for getting back to Canada. Sorry to have to say it but 'trapped in a foreign country, send cash' is an old scam. Make sure you really are talking to your fiancee - and I hope she isn't some hot Russian chick that you met on the internet last week.

If you're sure, call around to raise some money for the fare home. Don't send a circular email because it looks too scammy itself. In the last resort, the Canadian embassy might help unless she is a British citizen. Which she might well be, because otherwise immigration were asleep to let someone in the country with no money, no return ticket, dodgy story.

Comment: I don't think anyone is actually in the UK are they?

Comment: @AakashM If OP says his fiance is his childhood sweetheart, I might believe it. Scammers paying for an air fare seems unusual, so on the face of it you're probably right. "I've got no money now but have an inheritence coming" could easily be a line. If I were OP I would talk to a trusted friend or relative, and ask them to have my back, because I might not be thinking straight.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't seen the comment "she is over there on a flight bought by the bank".

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like a scam. How well do you know this fiancée?

There are no such processes as you describe, so chances are that the fiancée is a scammer and is making this up to milk you for money.

Comment: "***the*** fiance[e]"? I hope you know *your* fiance[e] quite well. It's possible s/he is being scammed him/herself though.